# How can I apply the variable variables concept to jQuery in this particular situation

Tags: jquery

I saw some posts about jQuery's lack of variable variables (like php) and I was wondering how do I handle a situation like this? When I want to use the variable "i" to select an array.

```
var arr1_1 = ["1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0"];
var arr1_2 = ["1","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1"];
var arr1_3 = ["0","0","0","1","1","1","0","0","0"];
var arr1_4 = ["0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1","1"];
var arr1_5 = ["0","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","0"];
var arr1_6 = ["1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0"];
var arr1_7 = ["0","1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0"];
var arr1_8 = ["0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0","1"];

for(var i=0; i <= 9; i++){
    console.log(
        arr1_"here is the i";
    )
}
```

Comment: You use a multi-dimensional array like a normal person.

Comment: your question is confusing. can you add some expected output>\

Comment: Consider using JSON. "jQuery" doesn't have variables - it's written in JavaScript, which DOES.

Comment: Burnzy's answer is amazing ;) Ty guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a better idea to store this as a hash, as your data will be structured.

```
var data = {
    "arr1_1": ["1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    "arr1_2": ["1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1"],
    "arr1_3": ["0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0"],
    "arr1_4": ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1"],
    "arr1_5": ["0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0"],
    "arr1_6": ["1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"],
    "arr1_7": ["0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0"],
    "arr1_8": ["0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1"],
}

for(var i=0; i <= 9; i++){
   console.log(
       data["arr1_" + i]
   )
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FNqSZ/)**

Comment: I check this answer because I believe it's a better way to go, reading what you all said. Ty!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can achieve what you are trying to do with the `eval` function

```
for(var i=0; i <= 9; i++){
    console.log(
        'here is the arr1_'+i+': ' + eval('arr1_'+i);
    )
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is really cool - this wasn't possible a few years ago, am I right? Is eval a jQuery function or a javascript one? Just checked , javascript one - but very clever :)

Comment: I'd avoid using `eval`, just for the semantic non-sense. If you need structured data, put them in a structure rather than fix it later.

Comment: I second what @Frederik.L says, avoid this as much as possible, even if it's feasible it doesn't mean it's recommended practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the variable by the bracket operator in JavaScript:

```
for(var i=0; i <= 9; i++) {
  var varName = 'arr1_'+(i+1);
  console.log(window[varName]);
}
```

Assuming that your array variables are within the 'window' scope.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an array of arrays:

```
var arr = [
    [] /* 0th index - confused about your example - start with 1? */
    ,["1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
    ,["1","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1"]
    ,["0","0","0","1","1","1","0","0","0"]
    ,["0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1","1"]
    ,["0","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","0"]
    ,["1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0"]
    ,["0","1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0"]
    ,["0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0","1"]
];

for(var i=0; i <= 9; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

You can then access individual members

```
arr[row][col];
```